# BFG which repo to use after successful run

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, bfg-repo-cleaner

I followed the documentation for using [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
I've read `"It's best to delete all old clones"` but not sure which one and HOW to delete it. I'm pushing everything to bitbucket.

I have 2 repos's dirs now

```
/.git
/.myproject.git/
```

Should I just delete both dirs and pull everything from bitbucket? 
should I mirror again?
or just delete `/.git` and rename `/.myproject.git/ => /.git?`

or what...?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to `clone --mirror` again.
That way, you don't have to make any assumption on the existing local repos, and the new clone won't reference them anyway (so no need to delete all clones)

Make sure you are in a folder which has no .git or xx.git in it and:

```
git clone --mirror https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo> <repo>.git
```

Then you can apply bfg to your new bare repo `<repo>.git`

But: if your data is not yet pushed to BitBucket (because it has big files which are preventing the push to complete), then yes, try and clone --mirror your current repo: `xxx/.git` (not the `.xxx.git`) elsewhere, and apply bfg on that new bare repo.